# how to I make sure facebook twitter etc icons in html email have a space between them

Tags: html-email

All the questions I've read on stackoverflow have had the opposite problem, of a space being added unnecessarily.

In my case, I tried adding styles to the email template to space out the icons, but none seem to work. For example:

```
<a href="http://www.instagram.com/thing" title="thing">
    <span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,serif;mso-fareast-language:EN-GB;text-decoration:none;padding:0.2cm 0.2cm 0.2cm 0.2cm">
        <img src="instagram.png" HSPACE="50" VSPACE="50">
    </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest way is to simply add a space PNG in between the icons.
This seems to work reliably in Outlook and Gmail.

```
<a href="http://www.instagram.com/thing" title="thing">
    <span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,serif;mso-fareast-language:EN-GB;text-decoration:none;padding:0.2cm 0.2cm 0.2cm 0.2cm">
        <img src="instagram.png" HSPACE="50" VSPACE="50">
    </span>
</a>
<img src="space.png" HSPACE="50" VSPACE="50">
```

Comment: how are you stacking these? In a row? Why not use a table?

Comment: they are in a table. For some reason html embedded in an email doesn't follow certain rules that a browser does. Gmail and Outlook are not honouring the style :padding or hspace or vspace attributes. Another example of different behaviour is that inline base64 images don't work in an email (when cut and paste from working webpage).

Comment: They do not, no. Outlook is literally pure evil to emails.  And there are articles written about this subject in nearly every major email platform. [Litmus](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/396-conditional-code-for-outlook) or [Mailchimp](https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/) but the best way is to add what I call the "Kitchen sink"

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="300" align="center">
 <tr>
  <td width="280" align="center">
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="275">
    <tr>
     <td align="center">
      <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/71be465a8d8b6e9c35e279697/images/c7f897c9-5491-41c5-b73a-40d1e29f1185.png" width="32px" height="32px" alt="facebook" vspace="10" hspace="25"/>
     </td>
     <td width="20">
     </td>
     <td align="center">
      <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/71be465a8d8b6e9c35e279697/images/9c7aac20-d385-4bde-a0cf-1ddb7d6f7060.png" width="32px" height="32px" alt="Twitter" vspace="10" hspace="25"/>
     </td>
     <td width="20">
     </td>
     <td align="center">
      <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/71be465a8d8b6e9c35e279697/images/3b801696-a19c-4de3-adbe-c4cb9976d40b.png" width="32px" height="32px" alt="Instagram" vspace="10" hspace="25"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Use nested tables and empty `<td>` with heights and/or widths. Tables are the best when it comes to HTML email.

Comment: If a spacing TD gets below 20 width or height it would also be good to set inline style font-size and line-height to 0px on the TD